# generate csv from mvc web api httpresponse and receive it by angularjs for download

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I am trying to generate a CSV file from my web api and receive that file through angularjs. I have an API controller like below:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GenerateCSV(FieldParameters fieldParams)
    {
        var output = new byte[] { };
        if (fieldParams!= null)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                this.Serialize(fieldParams, stream);
                stream.Flush();
                output = stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new ByteArrayContent(output) };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "Fields.csv"
        };
        return result;
    }
```

In my angularjs, i have this:

```
$scope.save = function () {
        var csvInput= extractDetails();

        // File is an angular resource. We call its save method here which
        // accesses the api above which should return the content of csv
        File.save(csvInput, function (content) {
            console.log(content);

            // only creates a csv file with "[object Object]" written in it
            var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
            hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\uFEFF' + encodeURI(content.Parameters);
            hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
            hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.csv';
            hiddenElement.click();
        });
    };
```

Lets say for example, in my API controller, the content of response is

> output
>
> {byte[152]}
>
> [0]: 83
>
> [1]: 101
>
> [2]: 44
>
> [3]: 67
>
> [4]: 10

When I receive this in **angularjs** and I put the value of `content` in the console log (chrome), this is what I get:

> {Parameters: Array[1], $promise: Object, $resolved: true, $get: function, $save: function…}
>
> 0:"S"
>
> 1: "e"
>
> 2: ","
>
> 3: "C"
>
> 4: "↵"
>
> $promise: object
>
> $resolved: true`

1. Why did the `content` received in the angularjs contain characters
   already instead of a byte of array?
2. How can I control the `content` in such a way that I will only use
       the csv related data and remove `$promise` and `$resolved`? Why are they included in the first place? How to remove them?
3. What is the proper way of generating a csv if what I am doing is
       wrong? :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forgot to update this, but i now found a way to solve this:

There will be two API's, one (POST) will remember the data to be used in the processing and another one (GET) which will dispense the file.

POST:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> BuildFile(FileParameters fileParams)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        if (fileParams!= null)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => FileContents.Add(guid, fileParams));
            return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Value = guid });
        }
        return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid data");
    }
```

In AngularJs, remember the guid returned and pass this to another api:

```
 location.href = '/api/file/generatefile' + '?guid=' + generatedGuidFromAPI + '&reportName=' + $scope.reportName;
```

And here is the `generatefile` API controller in MVC:

GET:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GenerateFile(string guid, string reportName)
    {
        byte[] output = null;
        if (FileContents.ContainsKey(guid))
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    this.CreateFile(FileContents[guid], stream);
                    stream.Flush();
                    output = stream.ToArray();
                }
            });
        }

        FileContents.Remove(guid);
        if (output != null)
        {
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new ByteArrayContent(output) };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = reportName + ".csv"
            };
            return result;
        }

        return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "No record found");
    }
```

using `location.href` will cause the browser to automatically download the file, asking you whether to save it or not.

Comment: but this uses server memory... any other answers??

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it: (tested in chrome)

```
    // WebAPI controller action
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string rpt, DateTime date)
    {
        List<DailyMIReportViewModel> list = new List<DailyMIReportViewModel>();

        // Do some stuff to generate list of items

        // Download Requested
        if (rpt == "dailymidl")
        {
            // Create byte array of csv
            byte[] csvData = WriteCsvWithHeaderToMemory(list);
            // create FileContentResult of cdv byte array
            FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(csvData, "application/octet-stream");
            // set filename in FileContentResult
            result.FileDownloadName = "Report.csv";

            return Ok(result);
        }
        // Data Requested
        return Ok(list);

        // Client-side angularjs
        // Called on button click
        $scope.generateMIDownload = function (forDate) {
            // Using $resource to return promise with FileContentResult payload
            reportsRepository.dailymidl(forDate).$promise.then(
            function (data) {
                //ok
                // NOTE: the base64 part is what got it working

                var dataUrl = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + data.FileContents
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                angular.element(link)
                  .attr('href', dataUrl)
                  .attr('download', data.FileDownloadName)
                  .attr('target','_blank')
                link.click();
            },
            function (response) {
                //not ok
            });
        }

        // Reports Repository (for ref)
        angular.module('msgnr').factory('reportsRepository', function ($resource) {
            return {
                dailymidl: function (date) {
                    return $resource('/api/Report/', { rpt: 'dailymidl', date: date, toDate: date }).get();
            }
        }
    });
```

Incase it helps anyone else.

Comment: You are doing an async server call using $resource and getting the csv/excel data in the successfunction and then when the anchor's click is invoked, it DOES NOT make a server call at that point, it just shows the file????

will it work without the target=_blank since popup blockers may fuss about that?

I have not used $resource before and our angular infrustructure is abstracted away, but I"m sure I could get to it if I wanted to.

Is there any length restriction on this dataUrl? Can long ones slow down the browser?

any code you can show regarding the reportsRepository

Comment: You are correct re the async call to the server using $resource and the anchors click does not make another call it just presents the file.
It works fine without target=_blank.  
There are length restrictions on a data url but its determined by the browser. I believe Chrome is 2Mb.
I've edited my prev response to include the reportsRepository