# A zip file is sent in response from server(using Java REST API). Javascript/angularjs code to download it on client side?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

In Java REST API:-

response.setContentType("application/oct-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\""file.zip\"");

If I receive the response in angularjs $http service, how can I make it downloadable. If only content was returned from Java APi, downloading in javascript is achievable. But how to work with it when a complete file is returned.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look to other questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490007/angularjs-download-pdf-file-from-the-server)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. An addition to it- set {responseType:'arraybuffer'} while making $http.get request so that downloaded zip file is not corrupted.