# Why in ASP.NET MVC I get JSON instead of FileDownload?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I want to make ability to download attachments from my site, (I need to make it runs in IE)
so in html I have:

```html
<a href="api/attachments/DownloaAttachment?id={{attachment.Id}}" target="_blank">
   Download Image
</a>
<!-- {{attachment.Id}} - it's because I use AngularJS  :)  -->
```

in controller:

```js
        [HttpGet]
        public FileContentResult DownloaAttachment(int id)
        {
            var att = GetAttachmentById(id);
            byte[] fileBytes = att.Content.Content;
            var response = new FileContentResult(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
            response.FileDownloadName = att.FileName;
            return response;
        }
```

but when I click on "Download Image" - I have a new window and responce from controller as json, like:

```html
{"FileContents":"/9j/4.. some bytes..ZK9k=","ContentType":"application/octet-stream","FileDownloadName":"Cover.jpg"}
```

But I don't need that JSON, I need to be able to download attach as file to user's computer.
How can I make it as simple file download? What am I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
var response = new FileContentResult(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
```

to:

```
var response = new FileContentResult(fileBytes, "image/jpeg");
```

Comment: I try to change as you wrote, but there is nothing changes. - Opens new window and I see {"FileContents":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRg...bla..bla..Afbs//Z","ContentType":"image/jpeg","FileDownloadName":"CoverBack.JPG"} right on a page..

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have tried - [Returning binary file from controller in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api).

It says return `HttpResponseMessage` and set `Content` of response = file content and set header content type.

Also, i would suggest to look into this - [Download file from an ASP.NET Web API method using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080018/download-file-from-a-webapi-method-using-angularjs).

It says, you also need to set `Content.Headers.ContentDisposition` and `Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName` .

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloaAttachment(int id)
    {
        var att = GetAttachmentById(id);
        byte[] fileBytes = att.Content.Content;
        var response = new FileContentResult(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        response.FileDownloadName = att.FileName;
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/*"));

    }
```

or if you have file extension pass on that instead of * in (image/*).

refer: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.mediatypeheadervalue(v=vs.118).aspx)