# Download large file (in GB) from a ASP.NET Web API method using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, file, download

I am able to download smaller files with AngularJS and Web API controller using the code provided in [Trying to download file from server using angularJS and c# webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289157/trying-to-download-file-from-server-using-angularjs-and-c-sharp-webapi)

But, I am getting error page when I try to download more than 1GB file. How to download large file (> 1GB) using AngularJS?

Comment: could you check your network tab in the developers console? is there maybe an error downloading?