# Failed to load PDF document - Angular JS - BLOB

Tags: angularjs, pdf, blob, asp.net-web-api, chunked-encoding

I am trying to get PDF document from Web API, and want to show in Angular App. Getting "Failed to load PDF document error". 
I have followed 
"[AngularJS: Display blob (.pdf) in an angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app)" post.
Whereas, i can download the same file successfully by following "[Download file from an ASP.NET Web API method using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080018/download-file-from-a-asp-net-web-api-method-using-angularjs)" post.

Looks like i am getting the file as "Chunked Transfer Encoded". Somehow this is not getting decoded when trying to show in angular app. Please advise.

Web API Code:

```
HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        var localFilePath = @"C:\Test.pdf";

        if (!File.Exists(localFilePath))
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
        }
        else
        {// serve the file to the client
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));                
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Test.pdf";
            result.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", "Test.pdf");
        }

        return result;
```

Angular Controller:

```
   myModule.controller("pdfviewerController", function ($scope, $http, $log, $sce) {
$http.post('/api/Sample/GetTestFile', {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
 .success(function (response) {      
  var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);            
 });
});
```

HTML Template:

```
<embed ng-src="{{content}}" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></embed>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

problem is there in controller.
`{responseType:'arraybuffer'}` is verymuch required. 
For `$http.get` - It should be second parameter.
For `$http.post` - It should be third parameter.

In above case, i am using $http.post and i have passed `{responseType:'arraybuffer'}` as second parameter.

`$http.post('/api/Sample/GetTestFile', {responseType:'arraybuffer'})`

Corrected code

`$http.post('/api/Sample/GetTestFile','', {responseType:'arraybuffer'})`