# How to generate blob from http response in java script?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, blob

I am a beginner in javascript and web programming
I am using node to create a pdf file and pipe it as an http response

On the client-side I am using angularjs to create blob from the response. 
Instead of getting a correct pdf file, i am getting a pdf page with a blank page. 
Did I created blob the wrong way? Is there something I missed?

I did try researching the internet, the closest thing I found is this:
[AngularJS: Display blob (.pdf) in an angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app)

but it still does not work after i followed the instructions

my code:

```js
 $http.get('pdf-page', null, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
   .success(function (res) {
   console.log(res);  
   var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
   var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
   window.open(fileURL);
});
```

result of console.log(res):

> > %PDF-1.3 %���� 5 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Contents 3 0 R /Resources 4 0 R
> >
> > > endobj 4 0 obj << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /Font << /F1 6 0 R
> > >
> > > endobj 7 0 obj << /Producer (��PDFKit) /Creator (��PDFKit) /CreationDate (D:20150121171417Z)
> > >       endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /Font /BaseFont /Helvetica /Subtype /Type1 /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
> > >       endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 1 0 R
> > >       endobj 1 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Count 1 /Kids [5 0 R]
> > >       endobj 3 0 obj << /Length 110 /Filter /FlateDecode
> > >       stream x�e�A QC�=E/�����`p!�^� ������o�^�$$�F���%�����_w+q3�l�6��&�����!�h8�a�e�ș�.�0�08vrpd�H6�k�֯Zo��<����
> > >       endstream endobj xref 0 8 0000000000 65535 f  0000000462 00000 n 
> > >       0000000413 00000 n  0000000519 00000 n  0000000119 00000 n  0000000015
> > >       00000 n  0000000316 00000 n  0000000208 00000 n  trailer << /Size 7
> > >       /Root 2 0 R /Info 7 0 R
> > >       startxref 701 %%EOF

Comment: Turns out I'm giving $http.get wrong arguments
Link to solution:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093736/failed-to-load-pdf-document-angular-js-blob][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093736/failed-to-load-pdf-document-angular-js-blob

Answer (score -2):

Turns out I'm giving $http.get wrong arguments Link to solution: [stackoverflow.com/questions/28093736/… [1]: stackoverflow.com/questions/28093736/… –

Comment: This link is incomplete.