# Send file from nodejs server to AngularJS client

Tags: angularjs, node.js, filesaver.js

I want to send file from node.js server to client on Angular. I'm using fileSaver.js on client.

Server:

```
res.download('123.txt', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('error');
    }
})
```

Cliet:

```
$http.post('/downloadFile').success(function(res){
   var file = new Blob([res]);
   saveAs(file, '123.txt');
}
```

But it works only with .txt files.
How to do this with other formats?

Answer (score 0):

check this:
[Failed to load PDF document - Angular JS - BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093736/failed-to-load-pdf-document-angular-js-blob)

set **responseType**:

```
$http.post('/downloadFile','', {responseType:'arraybuffer'}).success(function(res){.....}
```