# Returning base64 string from web API to download as pdf in angular2 says error in opening the file

Tags: angular

I tried the converting to blob but it says error in opening the file.

```
 var a = document.createElement("a");
 document.body.appendChild(a);
 a.href = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + fileData;
 a.download = 'fileName.pdf';
 a.click();
```

The above code is working fine but when i tried the code in the below links the solution dint work. can any one please help me where im missing. Because i have spent a day on it.

[Failed to load PDF document - Angular JS - BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093736/failed-to-load-pdf-document-angular-js-blob)

[PDF Blob is not showing content, Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046133/pdf-blob-is-not-showing-content-angular-2)

thanks,
priya

Comment: How did it not work? Was there an error? What does it say?

Comment: received blob(2100) like this format and file downloaded but while opening the file it says error. and downloaded file size was 1kb. The above code worked but the links i provided above didnot work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extended some more time on it and found the solution. This solution may help some one.

```
convertbase64toArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
  }
```

conversion should be base64 string to bufferarray then to blob.

Adding some more steps for @sanjay
you need to install filesave npm package ->  "file-saver": "^1.3.8",

```
npm install "file-saver": "^1.3.8"

var byteArr = this.convertbase64toArrayBuffer(base64string);
var blob = new Blob([byteArr], { type: 'application/pdf' });
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "filename" + extension);
```

Hope this helps

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the full solution. I am facing the same issue

Comment: Hi Sanjay i have added the rest of the code to the above answer. please upvote if the solution helps you