# Download a file via AngularJS promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, download, promise

I wrote an `ExportService.js` in AngularJS that submits HTTP POST request to remote service for downloading data. When the data is returned from remote service, I am struggling how to let the browser download the resolved promise (data). For example, my code basically is following:

```
ExportService.requestData(); //this returns a promise object.
```

In my **controller**, the code below waits for the promise to resolve/fail.

```
ExportService.requestData().then(function(data) {
   //how to process the data for download here?
    $log.info(JSON.stringify(data)); //print out the data

   }).catch(function(err) {
     //handle error here
  }).finally(function(complete){
     //complete the request here
  });
```

I think, essentially, how to convert the data stream to a file and let it download in the browser.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080018/download-file-from-a-asp-net-web-api-method-using-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

```
ExportService.requestData().then(function(result) {
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(result.data);
    window.open(fileURL, '_blank', ''); 
});
```