# Sending files to the browser with AngularJS, WebAPI, not triggering download?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

Pulling out my hair on this.

I have a GET request via angular:

```
x.DeliverFile = function(fileId) {
  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: myBase + "Services/DeliverFile?FileID=" + fileId,
    headers: myHeaders
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

And in WEB API:

```
If fileinfo.Exists Then
  Dim result As New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
  With result
    .Content = New StreamContent(New FileStream(fileinfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    .Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = New Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    .Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileinfo.Name
    .Content.Headers.ContentType = New Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream")

  End With
  Return result

  Else
    Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
End If
```

I've done this with httphandlers many times, but missing something obviously with web api.

I'm able to see the bytes in via console.log(data);

I can't figure out how to get the browser to trigger the download.

I read this post here: [Download file from an ASP.NET Web API method using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080018/download-file-from-a-asp-net-web-api-method-using-angularjs)

I'm having trouble accepting the "accepted answer", as there must be a way to trigger a download in a cross-browser compliant manner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) and then you can do this:

```
x.DeliverFile = function(fileId) {
  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: myBase + "Services/DeliverFile?FileID=" + fileId,
    headers: myHeaders
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    var blob = new Blob(data, {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, "fileName.txt");
  });
};
```

Comment: Looks like IE9 isn't supported. I'm stuck having to support it on this project. Or at least I don't think it is. Reading in detail. Thanks for your help.