# how to save textarea to file in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Not sure how to add [saveAs](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to angular controller below

```
var app = angular.module("myNoteApp", [])
 .controller("myNoteCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "";
  $scope.clear = function() {$scope.message = "";};
  $scope.save  = function() {
   var blob = new Blob($scope.message, {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
   saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt")};
});
```

assuming text is in some textarea

Comment: What specific problems / errors are you having?

Comment: I just don't know how to save file , btw this is example from http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_application.asp

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080018/download-file-from-a-asp-net-web-api-method-using-angularjs

Comment: that example is too complicated for me ;)

Comment: @irom could you post ur html as well?

Comment: This is from  w3schools.com/angular/angular_application.asp so basically <div ng-controller="myNoteApp">
<h2>My Note</h2>
<p><textarea ng-model="message" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></p>
<p>
<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
<button ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
</p>
</div>

Comment: [For example;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443238/save-json-to-file-in-angularjs) Just change headers;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution, based on: [Download file from an ASP.NET Web API method using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080018/download-file-from-a-asp-net-web-api-method-using-angularjs)

**HTML**

```
<a ng-click="downloadFile('fileName.txt', message)" >Download </a>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.downloadFile = function(filename, data) {

            var success = false;
            var contentType = 'text/plain;charset=utf-8';

            try
            {
                // Try using msSaveBlob if supported
                var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
                if(navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
                }
                else {
                    // Try using other saveBlob implementations, if available
                    var saveBlob = navigator.webkitSaveBlob || navigator.mozSaveBlob || navigator.saveBlob;
                    if(saveBlob === undefined) throw "Not supported";
                    saveBlob(blob, filename);
                }
                success = true;
            } catch(ex)
            {
                console.log("saveBlob method failed with the following exception:");
                console.log(ex);
            }

            if(!success)
            {
                // Get the blob url creator
                var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;
                if(urlCreator)
                {
                    // Try to use a download link
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    if('download' in link)
                    {
                        // Try to simulate a click
                        try
                        {
                            // Prepare a blob URL
                            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
                            var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
                            link.setAttribute('href', url);

                            // Set the download attribute (Supported in Chrome 14+ / Firefox 20+)
                            link.setAttribute("download", filename);

                            // Simulate clicking the download link
                            var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                            event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                            link.dispatchEvent(event);
                            console.log("Download link method with simulated click succeeded");
                            success = true;

                        } catch(ex) {
                            console.log("Download link method with simulated click failed with the following exception:");
                            console.log(ex);
                        }
                    }

                    if(!success)
                    {
                        // Fallback to window.location method
                        try
                        {
                            // Prepare a blob URL
                            // Use application/octet-stream when using window.location to force download
                            console.log("Trying download link method with window.location ...");
                            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: octetStreamMime });
                            var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
                            window.location = url;
                            console.log("Download link method with window.location succeeded");
                            success = true;
                        } catch(ex) {
                            console.log("Download link method with window.location failed with the following exception:");
                            console.log(ex);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            if(!success)
            {
                // Fallback to window.open method
                console.log("No methods worked for saving the arraybuffer, using last resort window.open.  Not Implemented");
                //window.open(httpPath, '_blank', '');
            }
        };
```

Comment: It is just one bug there in line:  var blob = new Blob([data], { type: octetStreamMime });  octetStreamMime  is undefined, need to use like this:  new Blob([data], { type: "application/octet-stream" });