# C# Bytes array to Javascript Blob to create and auto download PDF file

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf

I have web api in C# which returns bytes array of PDF file. Here is the C# code

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Download")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<byte[]>> DownloadFiles(int fileDocumentId)
    {

            var file = await _fileService.FetchFiles(fileDocumentId);
            return file.ArchiveData;
    }
```

This is how I call the web api using Javascript fetch.

```
function download(id) {
    fetch(`https://localhost:xxx/api/file/download?fileDocumentId=11`)
        .then(response => {
            debugger

            return response.json()
        })
        .then(result => {
            debugger
            console.log('Success:', result);       

            var file = new Blob([result], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            window.open(fileURL);         
        })

        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Request failed', error)
        });
}
```

The above did create and open a pdf file but it is corrupted.

In `console.log('Success:', result);`, the output in the console is something like below:

```
Success: 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
```

Since the actual output is too long, I have truncated it here.

After googling more, I also tried the below code which convert the bytes array into arrayBuffer before create the blob. It did create and download the PDF but when I open the PDF, that PDF is also corrupted.

```
function downloadpdf(pdfUrl) {
    debugger
    fetch(pdfUrl).then(resp => resp.arrayBuffer()).then(resp => {
        const file = new Blob([resp], { type: 'application/pdf' });

        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = fileURL;
        link.download = "FileName" + new Date() + ".pdf";
        link.click();
    });
}

downloadpdf('https://localhost:xxx/api/file/download?fileDocumentId=11')
```

For `FetchFiles` method, basically it read the PDF file and convert it into bytes array.

```
byte[] fileBytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(file);
```

Comment: I had the same issue before, I remember I it solved by closing the file stream, Also please share `FetchFiles` function content

Comment: @ElasticCode, I have added a line of code of `FetchFiles` method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download file from an ASP.NET Web API method using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080018/download-file-from-an-asp-net-web-api-method-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code returning byte array to JavaScript and you don't need to do that, just return it as `FileContentResult` which will write a binary file to the response and the browser will download it as a file even if you call the API directly in the browser.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Download")]
public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadFiles(int fileDocumentId)
{
    string filePath = fileDocumentId=11;

    var file = await _fileService.FetchFiles(fileDocumentId);
    string fileName = "FileName" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".pdf";

    return File(file.ArchiveData, "application/force-download", fileName);
}
```