# Download file from GET response

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ngresource

In my Angular app, I'm using `ngResource` to send a GET request to a WebAPI server. It simply looks like this:

```
vm.exportCSV = function() {
    languageResource.export(function(data) {

    });
}
```

The server returns a response with the header `Content-Type: text/csv` and content like this:

```
Key;Language;Value
1;Enlish;Blabla
2;German;blabla
```

I have added `ng-click='vm.exportCSV'` to a link, and want to download the file returned by the request when clicked. I tried to do it like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20300591/2358221), but this simply gives me a file containing `[object Object]`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I think the one that you are getting is good to proceed in code. However, if you want to see whats in the object, try using JSON.stringify(data)