# Angular 2 download .CSV file click event with authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, download, fileapi

I'm using a spring boot backend and my api uses a service to send data via an OutputStreamWriter. I can download this in Angular 2 using a click event like so:

**Typescript**

```
results(){
window.location.href='myapicall';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="results()"
                    class="btn btn-primary">Export</button>
```

This works just fine; however, I recently implemented security for my api endpoints and now I am receiving a 401 everytime I try to make the call because it's not sending a header.

I wrote a service that I can see the results in the console, but I can't seem to figure out how to download the file.

**DownloadFileService**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class DownloadFileService {

    headers:Headers;
    bearer: string;
    constructor(public http: Http) {}



    getFile(url:string) {
        this.bearer = 'Bearer '+ localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Authorization', this.bearer);

        return this.http.get(url, {headers: this.headers});
    }



}
```

I tried downloading the data via a blob as suggested in this post:
[How do I download a file with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138424/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-angular2)

The file that gets downloaded is of type File and the content is:

> Response with status: 200 OK for URL:my url

It doesn't actually download the data.

```
downloadFile(data: any){
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
        var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(url);
    }



    results(){
        // window.location.href='myapicall';   

         let resultURL =  'myapicall';

        this.downloadfileservice.getFile(resultURL).subscribe(data => this.downloadFile(data)),//console.log(data),
            error => console.log("Error downloading the file."),
            () => console.info("OK");



    }
```

Comment: You can go for this, if u want to create csv file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300547/download-csv-file-from-web-api-in-angular-js/64315710#64315710

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you just need to parse the body of the response i.e

```
let parsedResponse = data.text();
this.downloadFile(parsedResponse);
```

Also I would recommend you use [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to download files as even in 2016 there does not seem to be a standard way to do this across browsers.

```
let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
saveAs(blob, "data.txt");
```

For a more in depth guide check [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#parse-to-json)

Comment: That was the problem, thank you! I'm assuming I can probably do a map to text in my service. I will take a look at FileSaver.js, hoping it will fix my problem of saving as type file.

Comment: Do you happen to know what I need to add to my component to recognize the saveAs function? I tried: 
var FileSaver = require('file-saver'); but doesn't seem to work

Comment: what module loader are you using?

I'm using angular-cli which uses webpack. To include 3rd party libs you add the filepath to the lib in `angular-cli.json`. e.g Add the following `"scripts": ["../node_modules/file-saver/FileSaver.js"],

Comment: I'm using the angular2 seed:
https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed

I added it to my project config and tried adding the typings via npm i @types/file-saver --save

Comment: Actually that worked, my IDE was just throwing an error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300547/download-csv-file-from-web-api-in-angular-js/64315710#64315710

Answer (score 0):

I use `FileSaver`, too. If you have extension on client side, you can see that it will work properly for `CSV` files. You just need to add extension manually:

```
FileSaver.saveAs(res, 'export' + extension);
```