# How to save a csv coming from server to client angular 4?

Tags: angular, csv, filesaver.js

I want to try and use file-saver but not sure if or where the file is being saved.

I tried this: 
[Angular 2 download .CSV file click event with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40966096/angular-2-download-csv-file-click-event-with-authentication/40966227)
but how do we set the location of the file being saved?

Comment: ideally, location is taken by the browser's default location.

Comment: Thanks @Aravind Would you happen to know where exactly in the default folder? When I go here: /Users/rstorm1/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default on a mac there are quite a bit of directories in there. Searching local storage, databases, blob_storage, etc. is not turning up anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, very silly mistake. I failed to place **data** in brackets like this:

`let blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8" });`

After that, it saves the file automatically in downloads folder which is good enough.