# Angular 6 CSV download

Tags: php, angular, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I'm new to angular, currently i'm working in a project which needs an csv export. Here i'm using Angular 6 as frontend and laravel as backend

This is how i wrote laravel function using mattwebsite/excel

```
// Lead export to csv
public function downloadExcel(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('token');
    $token = $credentials['token'];
    $userid = $this->getUseridFromToken($token);
    $type = "xls";
    $data = DB::table('user_mailbox AS A')
                    ->select('A.id', 'A.name', 'A.email', 'A.phone', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(A.send_on, "%d / %b / %Y") as send_on'), 'B.listing_heading','B.listing_id','B.listing_heading', 'C.name')
                    ->leftjoin('broker_listing AS B', 'B.listing_id', '=', 'A.listing_id')
                    ->leftjoin('users AS C', 'C.id', '=', 'A.sent_by')
                    ->where('A.sent_to', $userid)
                    ->where('A.user_type', '1')
                    ->orderBy('A.id', 'desc')->get()->toArray(); 
    Excel::create('Lead_Export', function($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('Lead_Export', function($sheet) use ($data)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($data);
        });
    })->download($type);
}
```

This is how i wrote function in angular component

```
    // Download leads as excel
download_excel(){
  const fd = new FormData(); 
  fd.append('token',this.token);
  this.brokerleads.downloadLeads(fd).subscribe(
    data => this.handleResponsedwnload(data),
    error => this.handleErrordwnload(error)
  );
}
handleResponsedwnload(data){ console.log('test');
  const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/xls' });
  const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(url);
}
handleErrordwnload(data){

}
```

service is like this

```
  // Download as excel
  downloadLeads(data):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}downloadExcel`, data);   
  }
```

view

```
    <a class="export-leads" href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="download_excel()" >EXPORT LEADS</a>
```

while doing this i'm getting response like this but file is not downloading
[image]

Comment: If you want to create CSV file from response data then [go for this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300547/download-csv-file-from-web-api-in-angular-js/64315710#64315710)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be done using [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver/v/1.3.2):

`import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';`

```
this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}downloadExcel`, data, { responseType: 'blob' })
 .subscribe((resp: any) => {
    saveAs(resp, `filename.csv`)
 });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300547/download-csv-file-from-web-api-in-angular-js/64315710#64315710  If you want to create csv file from data.

Answer (score 3):

You need to navigate the browser to the route where the Excel file is made on the backend (in a new tab) either with a link `<a href="path" target="_blank">` or with `window.open`

The `->download()` function sets headers so that the file will be automatically downloaded.

When you fetch this data with an AJAX call (which is what `HttpClient` does) you simply get the binary data returned (which is what you see in your Response tab in Chrome developer tools).

(*There are front-end hacks to download a file retrieved by ajax such as creating a link element and clicking it with JavaScript (see below), but they can not be recommended*):

```
let fileName = 'filename.xlsx';
let a = document.createElement('a');

a.href = window.URL.createObjectUrl(responseData);
a.download = fileName;
a.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This function working for me to export csv,

```
downloadFile(data: any) {
    const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value; // specify how you want to handle null values here
    const header = Object.keys(data[0]);
    let csv = data.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','));
    csv.unshift(header.join(','));
    let csvArray = csv.join('\r\n');

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var blob = new Blob([csvArray], {type: 'text/csv' }),
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    a.href = url;
    a.download = "myFile.csv";
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    a.remove();
}
```