# How to download a file in angular, which is received as application/octet-stream

Tags: angular, download, angular6

I'm creating a webpage that has to download a file in CSV format. The REST API returns the file.

I get an error while accessing the API. I guess that is because the file is getting converted to JSON. How can I get it from the back end and handle it?

**service.ts**

```
return this.http.get(URL);
```

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 CSV download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55771863/angular-6-csv-download)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver/v/1.3.2)

`import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';`

```
this.http.post(url, resource, { responseType: 'blob' })
 .subscribe((resp: any) => {
    FileSaver.saveAs(resp, `filename.csv`)
 });
```

Comment: how can i get file name from response headers?

Answer (score 0):

**To convert octet-stream to any required data type.**
I had a similar situation where i converted OCTET-STREAM into pdf.

*Slight difference, might be helpful for others, I received json response and octet-stream Array was a field in that json response.*

> In this case, replace .pdf by .csv

**octet_array** is the array of octet values.

```
  let arr = new Uint8Array(octet_array);
        let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        let b = new Blob([arr], { type: 'application/octet-stream' })
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(b);
        downloadLink.setAttribute('download', "prescription.pdf");
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
        downloadLink.parentNode.removeChild(downloadLink);
```